# scrollbar doesn't expand to full screen

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

I need to add a scrollbar to a section of my program because they want it to show all the people instead of only one group that the other section show. In looking through SC, most of the scrollbar question use Tkinter instead of tkinter and use pack instead of grid. The problem that I have is that my code only creates a small scrollbar at the end of the first row. I have tried different variations of `sticky = E` but it doesn't create a full screen scrollbar. Can someone point me in the right direction using tkinter and grid in a class setting?

```
    class ButtonClickSignin(Frame):

        def __init__(self):

            self.win2 = Tk()
            self.win2.title('Sign-In')
            self.win2['bg'] = 'blue'
            self.win2.geometry('635x635+200+100')
            center(self.win2)

            self.canvas = Canvas(self.win2)
            Frame.__init__(self, self.win2)
            self.frame = Frame(self.canvas)
            self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.win2, orient = VERTICAL)
            self.scrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
            self.scrollbar.grid(column = 5)
            self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar.set)
            self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = self.frame)
            self.win2.bind('<Configure>', self.onFrameConfigure)

            self.checkbuttons()

        def checkbuttons(self):
            filenames = ['grade_pk.txt', 'grade_kinder.txt', 'grade_one.txt',
                    'grade_two.txt', 'grade_three.txt', 'grade_four.txt',
                    'grade_five.txt', 'grade_six.txt', 'grade_seven.txt',
                    'grade_eight.txt', 'grade_drop_in.txt']
            with open('sign_in.txt', 'w') as outfile:
                for names in filenames:
                    with open(names) as infile:
                        outfile.write(infile.read())
            rw = 0  
            cl = 0
            file = open('sign_in.txt', 'r')

            for name in file:

                cb1 = Checkbutton(self.win2, text = name, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,
                            height = 2, width = 22, background = 'blue')
                cb1.grid(row = rw, column = cl, padx = 8, pady = 8)
                cl += 1
                if cl == 3:
                    cl = 0
                    rw += 1
```

Comment: _"... In looking through SC..."_ - what is "SC"?

Comment: Your code is missing lots of pieces, and has dependencies on files that will prevent it from running. Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That should have been SO, don't know why I put SC.

Comment: ok, so what do you mean by "SO"? Stackoverflow?

Comment: Yes, Stack Overflow. I've seen it written that way in other posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run your code because it missing code and I don't have all of the input files that this depends on. However, I see several problems:

1. you never call `grid` on the canvas, so it is invisible,
2. you make all of the checkbuttons a child of the root window rather than
   a child of the frame.
3. by not explicitly specifying a row, the scrollbar is going into row 0 which
   is the same row as the first checkbutton. Because you didn't tell the 
   scrollbar to span more than one row it will always only be as tall as that
   row (which is only as tall as a checkbutton)
4. you aren't using the `sticky` option, so even if the space given to the 
   scrollbar is appropriate, the scrollbar will never fill it.

My advice is to completely start over. Create you window with just the canvas, and make sure it's visible. If you give the canvas a distinctive color initially, this will be easier to visualize.

Next, add the scrollbar and make sure it's visible. The scrollbar needs to be on the same row or rows as the canvas, and it needs to have a `sticky` value of "ns" (north, south). Do this -- and only this -- and make sure everything appears and resizes properly before continuing.

Once you have that, add a frame of a large, fixed size into the canvas. It needs to be much taller than the canvas so that you can make sure the scrollbar works. Give it a distinctive color, and make sure that the scrollbar will scroll it.

Only after you've done all that do you start to add widgets to the inner frame.

Comment: Thank you, it's working correctly now. This is the tutorial that I was looking for but couldn't find. Using a different color for each piece added really helped in seeing how it comes together.